# How to get to the Nth element of a vector of vectors where inner vectors might have different lengths?

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

Lets imagine we have a table:
`std::vector< std::vector<int> > table(3, std::vector<int>)` looking like this:

```
 11 21 31 41 45 51 61 
 71 81 91 10 19 29
 39 49 59 69 79 89 99 109
```

We are given some `int nThPos` number between 1 and N the total number of elements in `table` (here 21).

What would be the most efficient way to find the element corresponding to the element # `nThPos` or its coordinates ([row][col]) in the table?

For this particular case, it does not matter in which direction the table is flattened: if `nThPos == 8`, the result could be either 71 (i.e. [1][0]) or 91 (i.e. [1][2]).

Be ware: My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8094467/4083486). But I my case the inner-vectors have different lengths.

Comment: if the table is constant then you can store table as vector<int> and table rows as vector<int*> where each row will be pointer to its start in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't choose to maintain some side data (or to select an entirely different basic representation) then there is no more efficient method than the obvious way (iterate through the outer vector accumulating total size of inner vectors until you reach the right inner vector).

If efficiency matters, store your data differently.

Comment: My problem is that, most of the time, I will us the table to pick an element in a given row and not any element in the whole table. I could not think of a more efficient way to store my data for both use.

Comment: When you write "side data", what do you mean exactly? Store the lengths of the inner vectors in an other vector?

Comment: If efficiency doesn't matter for the less common case, just do the obvious.  If efficiency matters for all cases, there are more complex ways to store the data that gain major efficiency for the "whole" lookup while losing very little for the other lookup.  If the sizes change VERY rarely, then other representations have great efficiency for any lookup, losing big-time when the sizes change.  You need to look at efficiency as a compromise across all possible operations.

Comment: @Prolix It is faster to "hash" to the correct vector.  That hash table can be another vector that holds the beginning offset of each vector.

Comment: The most obvious (not necessarily best) "side data" would be a running total of the size of all earlier inner vectors, so you could binary search rather than linearly search.  That is expensive on size change for cheaper lookup.

Comment: The most obvious (not necessarily best) alternate representation would be linear storage of the main array, with a "row starts" vector giving the starting offset of each row (row_starts[n+1]) giving the limit offset of each row, so storing row lengths isn't needed).  Then either form of lookup is instant, and size changes are VERY expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Here a naïve implementation which seems to do simply the work :

```
std::array<size_t,2> give_coord(size_t idx, const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v) {
    std::vector<size_t> sizes(v.size());
    size_t n{0};
    std::generate(sizes.begin(),sizes.end(),[v,&n] { return v[n++].size(); }); // store the different dimensions
    size_t sum{sizes[0]}, i{1}, r{idx};
    while(idx >= sum) {
        r -= sizes[i-1];
        sum += sizes[i++];
    }
    return std::array<size_t,2>{{i-1,r}};
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79f92877a9457721)</kbd>**

Note that I consider that the index starts at `0` hence `7` represents `nThPos = 8` regarding OP question.

I would not recommend it if you need performance as said on other answer and comments.